# Variations in invocation of defpackage and in-package

Tags: common-lisp, identifier

In Graham's book “ANSI Common Lisp” (1996) p. 137 the example illustrating the use of *defpackage* and *in-package* goes like

```
(defpackage "MY-APPLICATION"
  (:use "COMMON-LISP" "MY-UTILITIES")
  (:nicknames "APP")
  (:export "WIN" "LOSE" "DRAW"))

(in-package my-application)
```

The *defpackage* invocation uses of character strings to convey package names and list exported symbols.  While this style can be seen in older codes the dominant usage today seems to be

```
(defpackage :my-application
  (:use :common-lisp :my-utilities)
  (:nicknames :app)
  (:export :win :lose :draw))

(in-package :my-application)
```

The regularity resulting from using the `:my-application` keyword both in the *defpackage* and in the *in-package* invocations is a minor but appreciable difference.

I speculate, the second forms reduces the size of the program in memory because the keywords are all interned in the *keyword* package while literal character strings stand for themselves and literal character strings with identical contents do not need to share their memory representations. (And if they did, strange results could follow from mutating one of these character strings!)

What are the actual differences between these two forms, and why is the latter preferred over the former?

Besides this, I occasionally see

```
;; Pay attention to the :export line
(defpackage :my-application
  (:use :common-lisp :my-utilities)
  (:nicknames :app)
  (:export #:win #:lose #:draw))

(in-package :my-application)
```

The `#` introduces a reader macro but I am not sure which effects it has on a keyword and not sure how it modifies the *defpackage* declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use uninterned symbols, like `#:my-package`.

## String designators

Common lisp has a notion of a [*string
designator*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator)
(see also [designators](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/01_dae.htm)).

This means that operationally symbols in
[`defpackage`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpkg.htm) are equivalent to
their names.

## Which designator to use?

You have 4 options:

### 1 Interned symbol

E.g.,

```
(defpackage my-package)
```

#### Advantage

Brevity

#### Disadvantage

Namespace pollution: the symbol `my-package` is now
[interned](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) in the current
[`*package*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pkg.htm).

### 2 Keyword

E.g.,

```
(defpackage :my-package)
```

#### Advantage

Moderate brevity (one extra character)

#### Disadvantage

Namespace pollution: the symbol `:my-package` is now
[interned](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) in the [standard package
KEYWORD](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_abc.htm).

### 3 String

E.g.,

```
(defpackage "MY-PACKAGE")
```

#### Advantage

No namespace pollution.

#### Disadvantages

- Ugly upcase
- 2 extra characters

### 4 Uninterned symbol

E.g.,

```
(defpackage #:my-package)
```

#### Advantage

No namespace pollution.

#### Disadvantages

2 extra characters

The "ugly prefix" is actually a desirable feature because this is the only context where I use uninterned symbols, and emacs highlights them nicely if you add

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'lisp-mode
 '(("\\(#:\\)\\(\\(\\s_\\|\\sw\\)*\\)"
    (1 font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)
    (2 font-lock-doc-face))))
```

to your `~/.emacs`.

Comment: Thank you for the crisp clear, quick and useful answer!

Comment: '#:' -> ugly prefix

Comment: @RainerJoswig: The "ugly prefix" is actually a desirable feature (IMO) because this is the only context where I use uninterned symbols, and emacs highlights them nicely.

Comment: The emacs I use doesn't highlight them "nicely".

Comment: @RainerJoswig: oops, I did not realize it was my customization, I now fixed that. BTW, congrats on your rep milestone ;-)

Comment: @sds: thanks! Great to see you here answering questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your example:

```
(defpackage "MY-APPLICATION"
  (:use "COMMON-LISP" "MY-UTILITIES")
  (:nicknames "APP")
  (:export "WIN" "LOSE" "DRAW"))

(in-package my-application)
```

One then typically writes:

```
(in-package "MY-APPLICATION")
```

If you use strings in `defpackage`, then you also would use strings in `in-package`.

One of the main advantages of using strings or un-interned symbols is to avoid 'polluting' packages with 'unwanted' symbols.

> I speculate, the second forms reduces the size of the program in memory because the keywords are all interned in the keyword package while literal character strings stand for themselves and literal character strings with identical contents do not need to share their memory representations. (And if they did, strange results could follow from mutating one of these character strings!)

That's implementation specific and depends on how the macros and the underlying data structures are implemented. For example in LispWorks for the package object: the package name is a string, the nicknames are strings, the use list is a list of package objects, and exported symbols are stored as symbols. Thus the data from the `defpackage` form is converted as necessary into these.

Note also what the Common Lisp operators for packages would return: `package-name` returns a string, `package-use-list` returns a list of package objects, `do-external-symbols` iterates over symbols. They don't use keywords or un-interned symbols.